# Return rows that has 3 or more consecutive values following pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried Tabibitosan method but no help. Can you please suggest some other solution for below scenario.

Using Oracle 11g:

Please find the below table format,

```
Region  Date      Value
East    1/1/2018    1
East    1/2/2018    1
East    1/3/2018    0
East    1/4/2018    1
East    1/6/2018    1
East    1/7/2018    0
West    1/9/2018    0
West    1/10/2018   0
West    2/3/2018    1
West    2/4/2018    1
West    2/5/2018    1
West    2/8/2018    0
West    2/9/2018    0
West    2/10/2018   0
West    2/11/2018   1
West    2/12/2018   0
West    2/13/2018   1
West    2/14/2018   1
West    2/17/2018   0
West    2/18/2018   0
West    2/19/2018   1
West    2/20/2018   0
West    2/21/2018   1
West    2/22/2018   0
West    2/23/2018   1
```

---

**My Output should contain the rows that has three or more consecutive 1's and with rows that has only one 0 between 1's.**

**Note:**  Group by region and Order by date.
The date in the Date column may not contain all the days. Say, in the above 1/6/2018 is missing which is fine. I need to look for 'Value' column that follows pattern when ordered by date and grouped by region.

```
East    1/1/2018    1
East    1/2/2018    1
East    1/3/2018    0
East    1/4/2018    1
East    1/6/2018    1

West    2/3/2018    1
West    2/4/2018    1
West    2/5/2018    1

West    2/11/2018   1
West    2/12/2018   0
West    2/13/2018   1
West    2/14/2018   1

West    2/19/2018   1
West    2/20/2018   0
West    2/21/2018   1
West    2/22/2018   0
West    2/23/2018   1
```

Comment: Why is 2-3 to 2-5 together -- that has both east and west

Comment: @Hogan - I have edited the question. please check now.

Comment: How should a 0 be handled if it is the first or the last row in a partition (by Region), followed (resp. preceded) by 1? Would it be the same as a single 0 between 1's?

Comment: Apparently not - the last row for East has value 0, and it is not included in the sequence. Still, it would be good if you could confirm. Also: What is your Oracle version? `match_recognize` may work even better than tabibitosan, but it is only available since Oracle 12.1.

Comment: Oh - never mind the question about Oracle version, I see it was right at the top. Still, keeping both my answers (one with `match_recognize`) for others who may find it helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is complicated by the requirement that the value be "masked" - 0 becomes 1 under some conditions. Otherwise it would be a straight application of the tabibitosan method. Moreover, in the final output you want the original values, not the masked ones, so we must be careful with what we keep and what we discard at each step.

Here is one way to solve the problem. Note that `DATE` is an Oracle keyword, so it shouldn't be used as a column name (it may not throw a syntax error, but it makes code harder to understand). I didn't check to see if `VALUE` is also a keyword; just to be safe, I changed both column names, to `DT` and `VAL`. (As you shall see, in my code I create columns `GRP` and `CT` for group and count respectively; `GROUP` and `COUNT` are Oracle keywords, so the same consideration applies.)

```
with
  inputs(region, dt, val) as (
    select 'East', to_date('1/1/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'East', to_date('1/2/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'East', to_date('1/3/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'East', to_date('1/4/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'East', to_date('1/6/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'East', to_date('1/7/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('1/9/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('1/10/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/3/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/4/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/5/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/8/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/9/2018' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/10/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/11/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/12/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/13/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/14/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/17/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/18/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/19/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/20/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/21/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/22/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 0 from dual union all
    select 'West', to_date('2/23/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual
  )
, prep(region, dt, val, adj_val) as (
    select region, dt, val,
           case when val = 1
                or   lag(val)  over (partition by region order by dt) = 1
                     and
                     lead(val) over (partition by region order by dt) = 1
                then 1 else 0 end
    from   inputs
  )
, tabibitosan(region, dt, val, adj_val, grp) as (
    select region, dt, val, adj_val,
           row_number() over (partition by region order by dt)
           - row_number() over (partition by region, adj_val order by dt)
    from   prep
  )
, group_counts(region, dt, val, ct) as (
    select region, dt, val, count(*) over (partition by region, grp)
    from   tabibitosan
    where  adj_val = 1
  )
select   region, dt, val
from     group_counts
where    ct >= 3
order by region, dt
;
```

Output:

```
REGION DT               VAL
------ --------- ----------
East   01-Jan-18          1
East   02-Jan-18          1
East   03-Jan-18          0
East   04-Jan-18          1
East   06-Jan-18          1
West   03-Feb-18          1
West   04-Feb-18          1
West   05-Feb-18          1
West   11-Feb-18          1
West   12-Feb-18          0
West   13-Feb-18          1
West   14-Feb-18          1
West   19-Feb-18          1
West   20-Feb-18          0
West   21-Feb-18          1
West   22-Feb-18          0
West   23-Feb-18          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how easy this problem can be solved with the `match_recognize` clause (which requires Oracle 12.1 or higher):

**EDIT**: I missed the OP's Oracle version, which is stated as 11g. So this solution will not help him/her; I am keeping this answer, though, for others who may find this helpful in the future.

```
select *
from   inputs
match_recognize(
  partition by region
  order by     dt
  all rows per match
  pattern      (a{3,})
  define       a as val = 1 or prev(val) = 1 and next(val) = 1
);
```

See my other answer (using the tabibitosan method) for input data in a `WITH` clause, and for the output (same as in the original post).

Comment: When you combine `AND` and `OR` condition then you should use brackets - even if they are not required, i.e. `a as val = 1 or (prev(val) = 1 and next(val) = 1)`. Most developers do not know AND/OR precedences by heart, unless they use it every day.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - obviously, I don't agree. "Should" is your opinion, to which you are entitled of course. My opinion is that people who don't know the precedence of AND and OR have no business writing computer programs of any kind.